# Way to verify if variable is a valid GD image resource?

Tags: php, gd, type-hinting

I have a class that accepts a GD image resource as one of its arguments. As far as I know, there is no way to type hint this since it is a resource and not an object. Is there a way to validate whether the supplied argument is a valid GD image resource (aside from further functionality using this resource failing)?

PS: Please do not mention ImageMagick in your answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [get_resource_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php) function should help you out.  Short of writing code and seeing what it return, I'm not sure what it's going to say for a GD resource, so you're on your own there.  Should be a good starting point, though!

Answer (score 15):

Starting with PHP 8.0, `get_resource_type` with a `GD` image argument, will throw a `Fatal Error`:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: get_resource_type(): Argument #1 ($resource) must be of type resource, GdImage given.

We should use `get_class()` function. PHP documentation states:

> Explicitly passing null as the object is no longer allowed as of PHP 7.2.0. The parameter is still optional and calling get_class() without a parameter from inside a class will work, but passing null now emits an E_WARNING notice.

So, the correct way to check this, in PHP 8.0 should be:

```
function is_gd_image($var) : bool {
    return (gettype($var) == "object" && get_class($var) == "GdImage");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

get_resource_type() returns "gd" if the resource is a gd image, so that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Steve was first however.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_resource($image) || $image instanceof \GdImage)
{

}
```

do a check